# Call to function doesn't work when arguments are included

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I've been trying to figure this out for a few weeks, off and on. Maybe someone else will see the obvious thing I'm missing.

At this point I'm simply trying to verify that the function is working; I'm not doing anything other than checking the passing of arguments from the HTML button to the function.

There are two buttons in play here. The first one sends the arguments, but does not work--the Logger.log("yeeHa") statement is not called. The seconds button sends no arguments, but does allow the Logger statement to be called.

```js
function runSetup(projectTitle,projectMgr,projectSponsor,datepicker,weeks) {
//function runSetup() {
    Logger.log("before the vars");
    var ptitle = projectTitle;
    var pMan = projectMgr;
    var pSpon = projectSponsor;
    var date = datepicker;
    var wks = weeks;
    var tHeader = "Project";
    var mHeader = "Project Manager";
    var sHeader = "Project Sponsor";
    Logger.log("yeeHa");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<head>
      
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
         $( function() {
           $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
       } );
    </script>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="container" style="padding: 10px; text-align:center;">
  
  <strong>Project Information</strong>
  <p></p>
 
  <div class="inline form-group">
    <label for="projectTitle">Project Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="projectTitle" style="width: 150px;">
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <div class="inline form-group">
    <label for="projectMgr">Project Manager</label>
    <input type="text" id="projectMgr" style="width: 150px;"> 
    <br>
  </div>
  
  <div class="inline form-group">
    <label for="projectSponsor">Project Sponsor</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="projectSponsor" style="width: 150px;"> 
    <p></p>

  </div>
  
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="start date">
  
<div class="inline form-group">
  <label for="state">Weeks</label>
  <input type="text" id="state" style="width: 40px;">
</div>
  
  <p></p>
  <!-- THIS BUTTON DOES NOT WORK -->
  <input type="button" class="create" name="ganntSetup" value="Setup Gannt" onClick="google.script.run.runSetup
    (document.getElementById('projectTitle').value;
     document.getElementById('projectMgr').value;
     document.getElementById('projectSponsor').value;
     document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
     document.getElementById('weeks').value;
  )" />
  <!-- THIS BUTTON WORKS BUT DOES NOT SEND NEEDED INFORMATION -->
  <input type="button" class="create" name="ganntSetup2" value="Setup Gannt2" onClick="google.script.run.runSetup()"/>
  
  <div>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <input type="button" name="Main Menu" value="Main Menu" onClick="google.script.run.mainSidebar()" />
  </div>
  
  </div>
    
  <div style=
        "width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%; 
        text-align:center;
        background-color:black;
        text-color:white;">
        <p><a href="http://www.fastadmin.solutions" target="blank"><b>©FastAdmin Solutions</b></a></p>
        </div>  
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Not sure what I'm missing that is not allowing this to process.

Comment: The console errors tell you whats wrong: don't put `;` at the end of the arguments you pass like : `value;` you need commas between arguments.

Comment: Your second call does not pass arguments to `runSetup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the values of the variables you are setting as the parameters of the function with commas (,), not semi-colons (;). Also, the input with the weeks value has an id of state, yet you are trying to get its value by using document.getElementById("weeks").

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<head>
      
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
         $( function() {
           $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
       } );
    </script>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="container" style="padding: 10px; text-align:center;">
  
  <strong>Project Information</strong>
  <p></p>
 
  <div class="inline form-group">
    <label for="projectTitle">Project Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="projectTitle" style="width: 150px;">
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <div class="inline form-group">
    <label for="projectMgr">Project Manager</label>
    <input type="text" id="projectMgr" style="width: 150px;"> 
    <br>
  </div>
  
  <div class="inline form-group">
    <label for="projectSponsor">Project Sponsor</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="projectSponsor" style="width: 150px;"> 
    <p></p>

  </div>
  
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="start date">
  
<div class="inline form-group">
  <label for="weeks">Weeks</label>
  <input type="text" id="weeks" style="width: 40px;">
  <!--Changed id to weeks instead of state.-->
</div>
  
  <p></p>
  <!–– THIS BUTTON DOES NOT WORK ––>
  <input type="button" class="create" name="ganntSetup" value="Setup Gannt" onClick="runSetup
    (document.getElementById('projectTitle').value,     document.getElementById('projectMgr').value,   document.getElementById('projectSponsor').value,
     document.getElementById('datepicker').value,
     document.getElementById('weeks').value
  )" />
  <!–– THIS BUTTON WORKS BUT DOES NOT SEND NEEDED INFORMATION ––>
  <input type="button" class="create" name="ganntSetup2" value="Setup Gannt2" onClick="google.script.run.runSetup()"/>
  
  <div>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <input type="button" name="Main Menu" value="Main Menu" onClick="google.script.run.mainSidebar()" />
  </div>
  
  </div>
    
  <div style=
        "width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%; 
        text-align:center;
        background-color:black;
        text-color:white;">
        <p><a href="http://www.fastadmin.solutions" target="blank"><b>©FastAdmin Solutions</b></a></p>
        </div>  
        </div>
        <script>
        
        function runSetup(projectTitle,projectMgr,projectSponsor,datepicker,weeks) {
//function runSetup() {
    console.log("before the vars");
    //Logger.log("before the vars");
    var ptitle = projectTitle;
    var pMan = projectMgr;
    var pSpon = projectSponsor;
    var date = datepicker;
    var wks = weeks;
    var tHeader = "Project";
    var mHeader = "Project Manager";
    var sHeader = "Project Sponsor";
    //Logger.log("yeeHa");
    console.log("yeeHa");
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RobCampbell My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

You have semi-colons after each item in the call to the function, I'm no JS pro but a semi-colon is a line terminator so shouldn't they be commas?

```
onClick="google.script.run.runSetup
    (document.getElementById('projectTitle').value,
     document.getElementById('projectMgr').value,
     document.getElementById('projectSponsor').value,
     document.getElementById('datepicker').value,
     document.getElementById('weeks').value
  )"
```

Outside of that, what exactly are the values the functions is receiving? Maybe try comparing what it is getting versus what you think you are sending.